# Difference between HOMO and LUMO and corresponding spectral gap in Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecules

Coming from a Quantum Computing background, I am familiar with the singular value definition of spectral gap, I am currently trying to run Quantum Chemistry simulations and I would like to know if $|\text{HOMO} - \text{LUMO}|$ is same as the singular value definition.

The singular value definition of the spectral gap is defined over Hamiltonians. It is the difference between the ground-state energy and the first excited energy, i.e. the difference between the smallest and the second smallest singular value of the Hamiltonian.

I am referring to the Pitt Quantum Repository ([link](https://pqr.pitt.edu/)) that provides me with details about molecules such as Methane ([link](https://pqr.pitt.edu/api/json/VNWKTOKETHGBQD-UHFFFAOYSA-N)) which contains molecular orbital energy levels along with HOMO and LUMO. I would like to know if I can use the difference in their value as spectral gap in Hartree units.

For the Hamiltonian representation as an operator, I plan on using Pennylane's repository ([link](https://pennylane.ai/datasets/qchem/ch4-molecule)) that performs HF transformation and STO-3G basis.

Comment: With what you have said above I think the best we can say is "maybe". Firstly quite to *what* approximation to the Schrödinger equation do the Hamiltonians you use in Quantum Computing correspond? If they are some kind of of post Hartee-Fock or post DFT there may well be no orbitals at all, so the HOMO-LUMO gap can't be talked about. in such a case it might be hoped that the HOMO-LUMO gap is a good approximation to the first excitation energy, this is essentially Koopman's theorem, but there's not guarantee it will be the case.

Comment: Secondly if in your calculations you do have orbitals quite how do you chose the zero of energy when calculating your Hamiltonians? If you choose it so the Hamiltonian is positive semi-definite then the Singular Value and Eigen Decompositions are the same, and hence the HOMO-LUMO gap and the first excitation energy as you define it above will be the same.  However is the Hamiltonian is *not* positive demi-definite I can't see why this correspondence should occur, but I haven't sat down and  done the maths.